# How to create custom labels at the ends of the x-axis in a faceted ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've created a plot (below) and basically want the left and right ends of each facet to state "Ov" and "Cx." I've tried using `scale_x_continuous` but the issue is that the x-axis for each facet is different.

What I have right now (image): [image: What I have right now (image)]

What I'd like to get ideally: [image: What I'd like to get ideally]

```r
all_prm %>% ggplot(aes(y_coord, prominence)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~interaction(ms, sample), scales="free_x") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(10000), labels=c("Ov")) +
    theme(
        axis.title.y=element_text(margin=margin(r=7)),
        axis.title.x=element_text(margin=margin(t=7)),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill='white', color='grey10')) +
    xlab("Oviduct-Cervical Axis") +
    ylab("Prominence")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom function to set the break points, in this case using the range of the x limit values with an adjustment argument to move the labels away from the axis limits relative to their scale.

Using the `iris` dataset:

```
break_range <- function(x, adjust = .025) {
  rng <- range(x)
  rng + diff(rng) * c(adjust, -adjust) 
}


ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Sepal.Length )) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(. ~ Species, nrow = 3, scales="free_x") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = break_range, labels = c("Ov", "Cx")) +
  theme(
    axis.title.y=element_text(margin=margin(r=7)),
    axis.title.x=element_text(margin=margin(t=7)),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill='white', color='grey10'))
```

[image]